# How to place events on a HTML table by time

Tags: javascript, html, schedule, timetable

I am trying to place events in my HTML table, however, I can only do it by 15-minute intervals as each cell is labeled by every 15 minutes. I change the background color to display when the event is happening. I use a start time and an end time, which is received from the database.

When I want to place an event which 8:30 to 12:30, it is able to select the cell that has 8:30 and 12:30 and fill in the middle. However, I am unable to put anything in between 8:30 to 8:45 as there is nothing to select. For example, I want to put an event from 8:35 to 12:25, however, there is nowhere to place this in the HTML id selectors.

How do I allow the HTML table to accept greater than just 15-minute intervals?
Is there a better way to place events on an HTML table rather than just changing the background color of the cell?

This is how it currently looks
[image: current schedular]

This is how it should look 
[image]

```
<tr id="4_RowTable">
<td id="r4days">Friday</td>
<td id="t_800_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_815_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_830_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_845_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_900_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_915_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_930_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_945_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1000_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1015_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1030_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1045_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1100_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1115_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1130_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1145_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1200_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1215_d_Friday" bgcolor="#0000FF"></td>
<td id="t_1230_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1245_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1300_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1315_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1330_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1345_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1400_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1415_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1430_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1445_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1500_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1515_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1530_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1545_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1600_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1615_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1630_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1645_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1700_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1715_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1730_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1745_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1800_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1815_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1830_d_Friday"></td>
<td id="t_1845_d_Friday"></td>
```

Comment: Is it okay to use more then only HTML language?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using JQuery and a bit of CSS for the front-end, with asp.net c# for the back-end with a Microsoft SQL database.

Comment: You may put a DIV inside any TD and control the width of DIV by setting a class on parent TD. You can define e.g. 4 classes for any quarter or more classes for more steps.

Comment: Why don't you render it with a razor for loop? If you do a double for loop you can make the render code a lot easyer.

Comment: I use a loop to fill out the needed boxes that have to be highlighted, I have only displayed the raw HTML to make it easier to understand. The main problem I have is that it doesn't work for time between 0 - 14 minutes, it only works for 0.00, 0:15, 0:30, 0:45;Ideally I would like to put an image of a bar in front of the correct start and end times, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS property `linear-gradient()` to start/end the blue color in different position within the cell. Using your example, if one cell is 15 minutes and we want to display the time as 5 minute intervals, set `linear-gradient` percentages roughly as `33%, 66% and 100%`

```html
<style>
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="background:blue">
      this cell means 8:30 to 8:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, 
               white 33%, blue 33% 66%, blue 66% 100%);">
      this cell means 8:35 to 8:45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right,
               white 33%, white 33% 66%, blue 66% 100%);">
      this cell means 8:40 to 8:45</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```